# Setting default options for all autocomplete input fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The question is really simple. Using `JQuery UI`, when we have several `datepickers` spread across our application, we can set default options for all of them using something like this:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
  changeMonth: true, 
  changeYear: true
});
```

How can i do this with all the `autocomplete` fields?
I want to set the default `delay` for all them to 1 second.

What have i tried? This, for no use.

```
$.autocomplete.setDefaults({
  delay: 1000
});
```

Apparently the `autocomplete` object doesn't have the `setDefaults` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this...may be it will solve your problem

`$('.ui-autocomplete-input').autocomplete({ delay: 1000 });

Comment: Good one. Although i had to put inside a document ready function.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery autocomplete options can be set [after initialization](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).  To do this for all of your autocomplete functions at once, you will have to set up a selector that covers all of your autocomplete fields.  For example, you could use the element's id as the individual selector and give all the inputs that are set with autocomplete a special class, then call something like:

```
     $(.autocompleteInputClass).autocomplete("option", "delay", 1000);
```